# "Вы" - с большой или с маленькой?

Tags: орфография

В каких случаях "Вы" пишется с большой буквы, а в каких - с маленькой?

Comment: По-моему, *"вы"* - это уже уважительное обращение, поэтому никогда не пишу его с большой буквы, так как считаю это излишним.

Comment: Почитайте переписку учёных. Они всегда обращаются друг к другу на "Вы". Пушкин писал: "Я вас люблю",но тогда, видимо, было ещё нечётко принято правило вежливого обращения. А может, лингвисты тогда думали так же, как Вы теперь. Но писать "вы" - это то же, что писать "е" вместо "ё", к примеру, в слове "ведро": то ли "ведро", то ли "вёдро".То ли единственное число, то ли множественное. Вечная наша русская неопределённость. "Хотели, как лучше, а получилось, как всегда". "вы" - уважительное обращение к двум старикам, а к одному - "Вы": всё логично, однозначно, никаких разночтений. О чём мы спорим?

Answer (score 4):

Местоимения *Вы*, *Ваш* пишутся с прописной буквы при обращении к одному лицу в текстах следующих жанров:

- личное письмо (выбор определяет сам пишущий, выражая/не выражая таким образом *особое* уважение к адресату);
- официальный документ (отношение пишущего к адресату не имеет значения);
- анкета (адресат - неконкретное лицо; отношение пишущего к адресату не имеет значения).

Выражение "личное письмо" здесь выступает в качестве альтернативного названия для эпистолярного жанра. Т.е. письмо называется личным не потому, что адресовано конкретному лицу, а потому, что оно имеет личный характер (не является публичным). Смысл слова "личное" здесь не как в выражении "личное обращение", а как в выражении "личный разговор". По сути, личное письмо - это письменная форма личного разговора.

В текстах иных жанров местоимения *вы*, *ваш* пишутся со строчной буквы.

При обращении к нескольким лицам местоимения *вы*, *ваш* пишутся со строчной буквы, вне зависимости как от степени уважения к адресатам, так и от жанра.

**UPD:** [Копия](http://web.archive.org/web/20081022205917/www.yandex.ru/info/you_full.html) официального ответа Института русского языка РАН (с печатью и штампом), на основе которого сформулирован этот ответ.

**UPD2:** Официальным этот ответ является в силу того, что он заверен гербовой печатью института, входящего в состав Российской Академии Наук. Подлинность подписей научных сотрудников удостоверена штампиком канцелярии.

Comment: @Shamov, представленный документ не является официальным ответом ИРЯ РАН, а линь мнением неких сотрудников. Столь полюбившийся вам "Штампик" носит нотариальный характер, предприятие заверяет подпись своего сотрудника по его требованию нп любых бумагах.   
Вы об этом прекрасно знаете.  

От имение организации (преприятия) документы мождет подписывать только лицо, обладаеющее правом первой подписи, т.е. руководлитель или лицо исполняющее его обязанностии. Зачем в очередной-то раз тень на плетень наводлить?

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы. Два научных сотрудника просто выразили в письме своё личное мнение, которое просто не может быть правильным, поскольку они совершенно не знают русского языка. В Институте русского языка работают только такие. При этом они обманом заставили руководителя своего института поставить гербовую печать (доступ к которой есть только у него и его замов).

Comment: Что вы несете, @Shamov? 
Какая гербовая печать?

Comment: Вы всё-таки определитесь, чем именно заверяется подпись сотрудников - штампиком или гербовой печатью.

Comment: Гербовой печатью заверяется подпись руководителя предприятия, в отдельных случаях другого подлномочного лица: главного бухгалтера,  руководителя отдела кадров и т.п. 
Штампик, строго говоря, сам по себе ничего не удостоверяет. Но насколько помню, это вы сказали, что именно штампик делает бумагу официальнвм ответом **организации**. Так что ваш вопрос - не совсем ко мне.
В случае, подобных рассматриваемому, руководитель своей подписью заверяет руку сотрудника, а печать - подпись руководителя.